# Getting values from Ruby objects in general?

Tags: ruby, oop

This and similar problems do I run into all the time, and I would like to understand the thought process behind getting values from objects, so I  can solve similar problems.

If you have a similar example that illustrates the same, then that is just a good.

**Question**

How to get the value of `Content-Length`?

And how did you get to the solution?

If I do `pp res` then I get

```
#<HTTP::Message:0x0055ab1ef42738
 @http_body=
  #<HTTP::Message::Body:0x0055ab1ef42698
   @body=
    "...",
   @chunk_size=nil,
   @positions=nil,
   @size=0>,
 @http_header=
  #<HTTP::Message::Headers:0x0055ab1ef42710
   @body_charset=nil,
   @body_date=nil,
   @body_encoding=#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>,
   @body_size=0,
   @body_type=nil,
   @chunked=false,
   @dumped=false,
   @header_item=
    [["Connection", "close"],
     ["Content-Type", "text/html"],
     ["Content-Length", "291"]],
   @http_version="1.1",
```

If I do `pp res.methods` then I see `http_header`, so I am temped to think that I can get closer to `Content-Length` by `pp res.http_header.header_item`, but this fails.

The output of `pp res.http_header.methods` is

```
[:[],
 :[]=,
 :dump,
 :delete,
 :add,
 :all,
 :get,
 :set,
 :request_query,
 :content_type,
 :body_encoding,
 :http_version,
 :http_version=,
 :set_headers,
 :request_uri,
 :request_absolute_uri,
 :request_absolute_uri=,
 :set_date_header,
 :request_method,
 :body_size,
 :chunked,
 :status_code,
 :reason_phrase,
 :body_type,
 :body_charset,
 :body_date,
 :init_connect_request,
 :init_request,
 :init_response,
 :status_code=,
 :content_type=,
 :contenttype,
 :contenttype=,
 :set_body_encoding,
 :body_size=,
 :create_query_uri,
 :create_query_part,
 :chunked=,
 :reason_phrase=,
 :request_uri=,
 :request_query=,
 :body_type=,
 :body_charset=,
 :body_date=,
 :methods,
 :singleton_methods,
 :protected_methods,
 :private_methods,
 :public_methods,
 :to_yaml,
 :to_yaml_properties,
 :psych_to_yaml,
 :pretty_print,
 :pretty_print_cycle,
 :pretty_print_instance_variables,
 :pretty_print_inspect,
 :instance_of?,
 :public_send,
 :instance_variable_get,
 :instance_variable_set,
 :instance_variable_defined?,
 :remove_instance_variable,
 :kind_of?,
 :instance_variables,
 :tap,
 :public_method,
 :singleton_method,
 :is_a?,
 :extend,
 :define_singleton_method,
 :method,
 :awesome_print,
 :to_enum,
 :enum_for,
 :awesome_inspect,
 :ai,
 :pretty_inspect,
 :<=>,
 :===,
 :=~,
 :!~,
 :eql?,
 :respond_to?,
 :freeze,
 :inspect,
 :display,
 :object_id,
 :send,
 :to_s,
 :nil?,
 :hash,
 :class,
 :singleton_class,
 :clone,
 :dup,
 :itself,
 :taint,
 :tainted?,
 :untaint,
 :untrust,
 :trust,
 :untrusted?,
 :frozen?,
 :!,
 :==,
 :!=,
 :__send__,
 :equal?,
 :instance_eval,
 :instance_exec,
 :__id__]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know which library you're using, but you can simply go with dirty getting instance variables:

```
arr = res.instance_variable_get(:@http_header).instance_variable_get(:@header_item)
```

Now, simply search through the array:

```
arr.find { |a| a.first == 'Content-Length' }.last
#=> "291"
```

Comment: Digging through the internals of an object is generally not a good idea. Instead, you should check the documentation of the object and use its public interface whenever possible. Usually, classes don't guaranteed anything about their internal representation. Any update can change this in any way while the external interface through the exposed methods will often stay stable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don't tell us what that object is. My best guess is that it is a [`HTTP::Message::Headers`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/HTTP/Message/Headers) object from the [`httpclient`](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) gem. If that is the case, then you get the Content-Length header using the [`HTTP::Message::Headers#[]`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/HTTP%2FMessage%2FHeaders:[]) method as per [the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient):

```
res.http_header['Content-Length']
```